# $\text{rank}(A)+\text{rank}(A-I)=n \iff A^2=A$. I don't know my mistake in my proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, projection-matrices, idempotents

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over a field $F$. Show that $A^2=A$ if and only if $\text{rank}(A)+\text{rank}(A-I)=n$.

My attempt:

1. $A^2=A \implies \text{rank}(A)+\text{rank}(A-I)=n$
   Using the lemma that $\text{rank}(AB)=\text{rank}(B)-\dim(\text{ker}(A)\bigcap \text{Im}(B))$, we can substitute $A$ for both $A$ and $B$ and get:
   $$\text{rank}(A^2)=\text{rank}(A)-\dim(\text{ker}(A)\bigcap \text{Im}(A))$$
   Since we have $A^2=A$, it follows that $\dim(\text{ker}(A)\bigcap \text{Im}(A))=0$, which implies that $\text{ker}(A)\bigcap \text{Im}(A)=\{0\}$. Now, if we suppose that $A^2x=0$, then the solution set of this equation is $\text{ker}(A)\bigcap \text{Im}(A)$. Hence, the only solution is the zero vector. By a theorem, this means that $A^2$ is invertible. Moreover, since $A^2=A$, we also have that $A$ is invertible. Therefore, we can multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ and obtain $A=I$. This gives us $\text{rank}(A)=n$ and $\text{rank}(A-I)=0$. Thus, $\text{rank}(A)+\text{rank}(A-I)=n$ as required.

However, the conclusion $A=I$ is incorrect. There exist other matrices that satisfy $A^2=A$ but are not the identity matrix. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix) for some examples. Where did I make a mistake in my proof?

Comment: When $A^2x=0$, it is the vector $y=Ax$ rather than $x$ that lies inside $\ker(A)\cap\operatorname{Im}(A)$.

Comment: @user1551 if $Ax=y$
 and $A^2x=0$
, then $Ay=0$
. That mean $y\in \text{ker}(A)$
. And because $Ax=y$
, it means $y\in \text{Im}(A)$
. So the conclusion should be true. I cannot find out where I am wrong.

Comment: Haven't you just repeated the above comment? The error then is when you write that $\{x:A^2 x = 0 \} = \mathrm{ker}(A) \cap \mathrm{Im}(A)$. In fact any vector in the kernel must satisfy $A^2 x = 0,$ since $A^2 x = A( Ax) = A (0) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since we have $A^2=A$, it follows that $\dim(\text{ker}(A)\bigcap \text{Im}(A))=0$, which implies that $\text{ker}(A)\bigcap \text{Im}(A)=\{0\}$.

So far so good.

> Now, if we suppose that $A^2x=0$, then the solution set of this equation is $\text{ker}(A)\bigcap \text{Im}(A)$.

This is the part that is incorrect. The solution set of this equation is the set of vectors $x$ satisfying $A^2 x = 0$, which will in this can be equal to $\ker(A)$ (since $\text{ker}(A)\bigcap \text{Im}(A)=\{0\}$). On the other hand, the set of vectors $Ax$ such that $A^2x = 0$ is indeed equal $\text{ker}(A)\bigcap \text{Im}(A)=\{0\}$. You seem to be confusing these distinct sets.